# Extracting combobox display data from fdf file using iText

Tags: pdf, itext, fdf

I need to read the fdf file to get the list options (via getListOptionDisplay) for a combo box, but when I invoke the getAcroFields method on the fdfReader, the fields come back as empty. I'm using an older version (2.1.2), any suggestions or code samples?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I couldnt use the inherited methods, but I reviewed the fdfReader object in the debugger and was able to extract the information.